# How to perform a LEFT JOIN joining on fields only if not null?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of items which are categorised in up to three buckets: `cat1`, `cat2` and `cat3`. I want to apply a label to each row based on a lookup table which specifies the minimum conditions for each label: for example, some labels may have the condition that cat1 and cat2 are particular values but cat3 is specified as null - i.e. it can be any value.

For example, if these are the `itemData` and `lookupTable` tables below

[image]
[image]

I want to return the following values:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hack in JOIN condition to replace null values in `lookup` table with corresponding values in `itemData`. Note that this is only possible in `JOIN` statement not in `left outer join` . We use `WITH` clause and another query to also add rows which do not have any mapping in look up table

```sql
WITH mappedcategories AS
  (
SELECT 
    ID.item_id,
    LT.label
FROM
itemData ID
JOIN 
lookupTable LT 
ON
  ID.cat1 = IFNULL(LT.cat1,ID.cat1) AND /* replacing nulls with cat from Itemdata */
  ID.cat2 = IFNULL(LT.cat2,ID.cat2) AND
  ID.cat3 = IFNULL(LT.cat3,ID.cat3)
 )
SELECT 
  ID.item_id,
  ID.cat1,
  ID.cat2,
  ID.cat3,
  MC.label
FROM
  itemData ID LEFT JOIN /* left join to include rows with no mapping */
  mappedcategories MC
  ON ID.item_id = MC.item_id
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```